# how to use matlab vision.ForegroundDetector with webcam

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, background-subtraction, matlab-cvst

How to use matlab vision.ForegroundDetector with webcam instead of input video file.

```
hsrc = vision.VideoFileReader('viptraffic.avi','ImageColorSpace','Intensity','VideoOutputDataType','uint8');
hfg = vision.ForegroundDetector(...
       'NumTrainingFrames', 5, ... % 5 because of short video
       'InitialVariance', 30*30); % initial standard deviation of 30
hblob = vision.BlobAnalysis(...
       'CentroidOutputPort', false, 'AreaOutputPort', false, ...
       'BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
       'MinimumBlobAreaSource', 'Property', 'MinimumBlobArea', 250);
hsi = vision.ShapeInserter('BorderColor','White');

hsnk = vision.VideoPlayer();
while ~isDone(hsrc)
     frame  = step(hsrc);
     fgMask = step(hfg, frame);
     bbox   = step(hblob, fgMask);
     out    = step(hsi, frame, bbox); % draw bounding boxes around cars
     step(hsnk, out); % view results in the video player
end
release(hsnk);
release(hsrc);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the Image Acquisition Toolbox, you could replace the first line with:

```
hsrc = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 1, 'MJPG_640x480', ...
    'ReturnedColorSpace','grayscale', 'ReturnedDataType','uint8');
```

You will need to adjust the parameters according to the supported formats by your webcam. Just consult the documentation of the [`imaq.VideoDevice`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/imaq.videodevice.html) function.

Also replace the loop test by just `while true` since the video feed is always not done :)